# combining multiple arrays of different types and printing them

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to combine the 3 arrays in the Arrays growRate, plantMaturityRate and, fruitMaturityRate setUp as well as the Array pepperType(found in the main method) so I can print it. Ineed to be able to call peperData.toString()
I also cant use multidimension arrays

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HotPepperRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int answer;
        String[] peperType = {"Jalapeno","Serrano","Habanero","Poblano","Pimiento"};//Names
        System.out.println("Number of Peppers to simulate growth: 5");
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i +" "+ peperType[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("Select the pepper number you want to simulate growth: ");

       
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        answer = keyboard.nextInt();
       
        HotPepper[] peperData = (setUp(answer,peperType));
        
    }
   
    public static HotPepper[] setUp(int answer, String[] peperType)
    {
        int[] growthRate = {1,2,4,6,8};//1-8
        int[] plantMaturityRate = {12,14,16,18,20};//10-20
        int[] fruitMaturityRate = {1,2,3,2,1};//1-3
       
        //HotPepper[] peperDataTemp = new HotPepper[5];
       
        for(int i = answer; i==answer;i++)//combinds all of the arrays and sends it to the runner
        {
            HotPepper[] peperDataTemp = {(peperType[i]),(growthRate[i]),(plantMaturityRate[i]),(fruitMaturityRate[i])};
        }
        System.out.println(peperDataTemp);
        //return peperDataTemp;
       
    }
   
}
```

Comment: You've posted a list of needed requirements and quite a bit of unexplained code, but you haven't yet asked a clear, specific, clearly explained question, and this can harm your question.  Also, while homework questions are allowed on this site, these questions still need to meet all site quality and topic appropriateness requirements as per the [ask], [tour], [help] and the [How do I ask and answer Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852) links. Please check these out and then consider editing and improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to represent entities as rows across multiple arrays is awkward and error-prone.

Better to use the [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) features of Java.

For each of your arrays, define a member field on a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```
record Pepper ( String variety , int growthRate , int plantMaturityRate , int fruitMaturityRate ) {}
```

Populate.

```
List < Pepper > peppers =
    List.of( 
        new Pepper( "Jalapeno" , 1 , 12 , 1 ) ,
        new Pepper( "Serrano" , 2 , 14 , 2 ) ,
        new Pepper( "Habanero" , 4 , 16 , 3 ) ,
        new Pepper( "Poblano" , 6 , 18 , 2 ) ,
        new Pepper( "Pimiento" , 8 , 20 , 1 ) 
    )
;

System.out.println( peppers ) ;
```

When run:

> [Pepper[variety=Jalapeno, growthRate=1, plantMaturityRate=12, fruitMaturityRate=1], Pepper[variety=Serrano, growthRate=2, plantMaturityRate=14, fruitMaturityRate=2], Pepper[variety=Habanero, growthRate=4, plantMaturityRate=16, fruitMaturityRate=3], Pepper[variety=Poblano, growthRate=6, plantMaturityRate=18, fruitMaturityRate=2], Pepper[variety=Pimiento, growthRate=8, plantMaturityRate=20, fruitMaturityRate=1]]

Answer (score 0):

To combine the arrays growthRate, plantMaturityRate, and fruitMaturityRate with the pepperType array, you can create an array of HotPepper objects and set each object's properties using the values from the corresponding arrays. Here's what setup should look like:

```
public static HotPepper[] setUp(int answer, String[] pepperType) {
int[] growthRate = {1, 2, 4, 6, 8}; // 1-8
int[] plantMaturityRate = {12, 14, 16, 18, 20}; // 10-20
int[] fruitMaturityRate = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1}; // 1-3

HotPepper[] peppers = new HotPepper[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    peppers[i] = new HotPepper(pepperType[i], growthRate[i], plantMaturityRate[i], fruitMaturityRate[i]);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(peppers));
return peppers;
```

}

In this, a new HotPepper object is created for every index of the arrays, and the object's properties are set using the corresponding values from the arrays. The resulting array of HotPepper objects is then printed and returned.

Also, remember that the HotPepper class needs to have a constructor that accepts the String name, int growth rate, int plant maturity rate, and int fruit maturity rate as arguments in order for this code to work. If the HotPepper class doesn't have such a constructor, you'll need to add one.